# How can I programatically set the values of the jQuery dropdown-check-list?

Tags: jquery, dom, drop-down-menu, scripting

How can I programatically set some checkboxes to selected?

The scenario is as follows:
Once I create a user through the admin screen I have a couple of jqueryDropdown checkboxes one for "User Roles" and one for "User Regions" since a user can have many roles and many regions associated with him/her. No problem there I got that accomplished and saved to the database.
I also give the user the ability to update the user roles and regions and I want to do it through the jQuery dropdown-check-list so my approach is as follows:

1. Give them the same screen they used to create the user
2. Issue an Ajax request to get the user specific roles and regions.
3. Now what I want to do is based on the Ajax response set to checked the checkboxes that match the value of the response through DOM Scripting. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375334/jquery-dropdown-checklist-plugin-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own problem. First I want to mention that I wanted to populate this jquery component http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html  sorry if my original question was missleading.

**The Javascript to populate my jquery drop down checklist plugin is as follows:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //These will apply the jquery drop down checklist to both of selects
    $(".s1").dropdownchecklist({ width: 205});
    $( "button, input:button", null).button();
    loadUserRoles();
    loadUserRegions();
});


function loadUserRoles(){

    var userName = $("#userName").val();
    var hostname = getHostName();
var requestURL = hostname.concat("fos", "/users/userRoles?userName="+userName);

    $.getJSON(requestURL, null, function(data){
        var userRoles = new Array();

        $.each(data.list, function(i,item){
            userRoles.push(item.id.toString());
        });

        $("#role").dropdownchecklist("destroy");
        $("#role").val(userRoles);
        $("#role").dropdownchecklist();
        //$("#role").dropdownchecklist("refresh");
});
}

function loadUserRegions(){

    var userName = $("#userName").val();
    var hostname = getHostName();
var requestURL = hostname.concat("fos", "/users/userRegions?userName="+userName);

    $.getJSON(requestURL, null, function(data){
        var userRegions = new Array();

        $.each(data.list, function(i,item){
            userRegions.push(item.id.toString());
        });

         $("#region").dropdownchecklist("destroy");
         $("#region").val(userRegions);
         $("#region").dropdownchecklist();
});
}

function getHostName(){

var url = document.URL;
var rv = url.indexOf("fos");
var hostname = url.substring(0, rv);
return hostname;
}
```

**My grails action that returns JSON is as Follows**

```
def userRoles = {

  /* This action gets the user roles and returns it as JSON*/
    def user = Users.findByUserName(params["userName"])
    def rolesInstanceList = Authorities.findAllByUser(user)

    def outputList = new JSONObject()
    def rolesList = new JSONArray()
    def jsonRole = null

    rolesInstanceList.each {
      jsonRole = new JSONObject()
      def role = it.role
      jsonRole.put("id", role.id)
      jsonRole.put("roleName", role.roleName)
      rolesList.put(jsonRole)
    }
    outputList.put("list", rolesList)
    render outputList as JSON      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your question with your solution. It helps people in the future who may have a similar problem to you.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a class structure, where a DDCL is created generically and the code:

```
$('#selectorid').dropdownchecklist('destroy');
```

destroys the integrity of the DDCL that was initially created.

I found that this solution works much better for my application:

```
$('#selectorid').val(values);
$('#selectorid').dropdownchecklist('refresh');
```

where 'values' is an array of values (e.g. [1, 2, 3]).  This does not destroy the integrity of the DDCL initially created.

Answer (score 0):

Return some JSON with the state...

```
{
  "roles": {
    "role1": true,
    "role2": false
  },
  ...
}
```

Then some jQuery should do it...

```
$.each(json.roles, function(role, state) {

   $(':checkbox[name="' + role + '"]')[0].checked = state;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I need to make it work with this jQuery component here http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html It is not a regular checkbox component.